# RSNNS Radial Basis Function Interpolation when the output is longer than the input

Tags: r, neural-network, interpolation

Is it possible to use the RSNNS library to perform RBF interpolation when the target output is longer than the input?

There are 4 columns, "fitted" which stands for a value for each surf_x, surf_y, and surf_z value. surf_x etc. and all values of "outputs" all represent a coordinate in 3D space.

The goal is to use RBF interpolation to find the "fitted" value corresponding to the coordinates found in "outputs" where all values of surf_x in "inputs" can be found in column [,1] of "outputs".

```
library(RSNNS)

> dim(inputs)
[1] 2312    4

> head(inputs)
      fitted    surf_x    surf_y   surf_z
1 -2.0260418 -64.20550 -84.79310 219.4273
2  1.2358981 -67.00667 -79.65610 227.9487
3 -1.3667838 -62.88993 -86.83528 218.1500
4  0.1172459 -66.91177 -79.44738 227.0095
5  1.1278194 -67.30763 -80.56429 226.5518
6 -2.7412495 -62.88353 -85.40290 218.0784

> dim(outputs)
[1] 6971    3

> head(outputs)
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,] -38.000 -41.794 180.858
[2,] -39.542 -50.167 175.664
[3,] -33.440 -56.959 173.340
[4,] -17.804 -60.643 181.561
[5,]  -8.156 -50.190 201.004
[6,] -23.019 -36.171 196.698

rbf_res <- RSNNS::rbf(x = inputs,
               y = outputs)

Error in checkInput(x, y) : nrows of 'x' and 'y' must match
```